# Boxing of NSString stringWithFormat like NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

We can create an NSNumber like this

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.5];
//or
NSNumber *number = @(4.5);
//or
NSNumber *number = @4.5;
```

I know we can convert to an NSString with the following statement

```
NSString *string = @("stuff"); //equivalent of [NSString stringWithUTF8String]
```

However, can we create an NSString like this?

```
NSString *string = @(@"Name is:%@",name); //equivalent of [NSString stringWithFormat]
```

Comment: You can simply type that in xcode and you will have your answer.

Comment: Yeah, If you request to Apple to introduce this feature. :)

Comment: @thandasoru hey change your profile name man

Comment: @Chiquis I tried, since it didn't work I thought there might be some syntactic sugar which I didn't know. Hence I asked in this forum :-)

Wow, So many negative markings for this question :D Requesting to close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head. 
I do not think there's any syntactic sugar for this.

Though, I believe you could achieve what you are looking for like this:

Put this in your .pch file

```
#define format(s, ...) 
[NSString stringWithFormat:s, ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

And call it :

```
NSString *s = format(@"%@, %@", @"a", @"b");
```

Comment: Nice one, anyway I've requested to close the question because it received many negative marks.

Comment: Small type `[NSString stringWithFormat:s, ##__VA_ARGS__)]` has extra `)`, should be `[NSString stringWithFormat:s, ##__VA_ARGS__]`

Comment: @bauerMusic ty, Edited